# lost of packages on UdpClient receiver

Tags: c#, network-programming

My application using UdpClient to receive images from some other machine.
Each image size is 951000 bytes and MTU limit is 1500 bytes.

So the sender application must use fragmentation ... and each sending package contain header that contain 2 int

1. total_number
2. current_number

The code receiving bytes .. .and this is very intensive bit rate because the video have new frame to send to my application every 30 milisecond ..

I found myself losing packages and i don't know how to do it different and not to lose packages.

Someone have any idea how to solve this ? 
Is there any better way ?

this is the code

```
public class PackagePartial
{
    public int total_count;
    public int current_count; // first package is 1  
    public byte[] buffer;

    public byte[] Serializable()
    {
        // make the Serialize
    }

    public static void DeSerializable(byte[] v)
    {
        total_count = ... ;
        current_count = ... 
        buffer = ... 
    }
}

// the network layer 
int lastPackIndex = 0;
List<byte> collection = new List<byte>();
while(true)
{
      byte[] package = _clientListener.Receive(ref ep);

       PackagePartial p = PackagePartial.DeSerializable(package);

       // indication that i lost package
       if(p.current_count - lastPackIndex != 1 )
       {
         collection.Clear();
         lastPackIndex = 0
         continue;               

       }

       if(p.current_count == p.total_count)
       {
             // image Serialize and send it to the GUI layer as bitmap 
             Image img = ConvertBytesToImage(collection);

             SendToGui(img);

             collection.Clear();

             lastPackIndex = 0

       }
       else
       {
             lastPackIndex = p.current_count
             collection.AddRange(p.Buffer)
       }
```

Comment: The usual approach is to employ compression (such as H.264) to reduce the size of the data sent.

Comment: There is no way to compression - this is something that i can't control and handle with :(

Comment: Try to sgnificantly increase listener.Client.ReceiveBufferSize

Comment: @Yanshof: I don't believe you.

Comment: Graffito@ thanks ... i try but this is not help

Answer (score 0):

Don't deserialize each package to an intermediate class after recieve.

Create a List of byte arrays and stuff them all in there as they come in.

Once the other side finishes sending, look in the first one to find the total count and see if the List.Count matches the total count.

If it does, you have all of the packages, now you can reassemble the image, just disregard the headers, you don't need them anymore.

Since you don't need anything at this point but the data from each packet, assembling the image should be faster (no serialization to an intermediate class involved anymore).

This should minimize the processing required for each image.

Comment: no can do ... the deserilaize take 0.459 milliseconds (less then one milliseconds) - so this is not the problem

Comment: You said you are receiving at an image every 30 milliseconds, 951000/1500 = 634, 634 * .459 = 291.006. This means you are spending 291 milliseconds deserializing when you need to be ready for the next frame every 30 milliseconds. How can shaving almost 300 milliseconds off your image processing time not help?

Comment: i cant do it without the deserialize. i must know and update the gui in case sime packate didnt get to me or lost.

Comment: and the other side is not stopping send :-(

Comment: That is why you check the first int in the first package in the list and compare to the list.count, if they don't match you lost packages. If you check after each image is received, and you are getting images at 1 every 30 milliseconds, you are going to know packages are missing in, at most, 30 milliseconds.

Comment: The other side not stopping send is another reason you dont need to check after each package, What difference will it make if you know a package is missing in 20 milliseconds as opposed to 30 milliseconds, they are going to send until they have sent them all anyway.

Comment: sorry .. this is totally not the problem. I already do it now ... check only the first int on the incoming package